# How to split database of WordPress multi-site network into multiple database

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I am working on an WordPress multi-site network.Our multi-site network is going to be increase more than 1000 sites (sub site).As i have seen in database every new site create 10 new database tables .So if my network increases up-to 1000 sites then there will be 10000 tables in database.

**I want to avoid this and spit this tables into multiple databases.**

For this i researched on internet and found WPMU's `MULTI DB` plugin but which is not available anymore.

Plz suggest me solutions for this or any plug-in(paid/unpaid)

Comment: One of the features of MultiSite is that all the WP instances use a single WP installation, and a single database, just with different tables.

WP Multisite has no limit, on creating on sites. But make sure you have purchased a better hosting account data limit according to your site sizes. 

Having each site on a separate DB defeats the point of mutisite. If you're worried about other blogs being able to see the content of others, that won't happen. Security won't be an issue either, provided your clients secure their blogs, themes and plugins.

Comment: Yes i know it uses single database and there is no limit to create blogs.But if it creates 5000 blogs then there will be 50000 table's in single database. And don't want that much tables in one db so want to split them into multiple databases even i had dedicated server.

Comment: Multi-DB is still available. I used it last year without issues. I is just not supported by WPMU anymore. https://github.com/wpmudev/multi-db

Comment: @DavidLabbe it is available on GitHub where its entire code using mysql. And i want to use that with php7

Comment: I am confused. Why can't you use it with php7?

Comment: WordPress 4.8 using using mysqli. So if you try to install plugin with WordPress 4.7 running on php 7 not works.